# Check for valid dates using SAS macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have written a macro to check for invalid dates and set it to '11111111', but got an unexpected  **NOTE: Invalid argument to function INPUT**. The reason for the note is, source data has date "0212-04-26" which is beyond the SAS dates ranging A.D. 1582 to A.D. 19,900. So now I'm looking to check for invalid date without any message`.

My Code:

```
  %macro chkdate(datefld=, num_date=) ;
  /* invalid date gets set to '11111111'    */
    if &datefld ne '0001-01-01' then do ;
     t_date = input(compress(&datefld, '-'), yymmdd8.) ;
       if t_date eq . then do ;
          %errors( key_desc=Invalid Date, fname=&datefld,)
          &datefld = '11111111' ;
       end;
    end;
  %mend chkdate ;
```

thanks

Comment: The `num_date=` argument is not used anywhere in the macro...

Comment: @DominicComtois sorry I have modified the macro before posting it here. As the question is mainly on   t_date = input(compress(&datefld, '-'), yymmdd8.) ;.

Answer (score 2):

Different approaches exist...

I'd recommend reading [this paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/122-2013.pdf) which illustrates the `?` and `??` informat modifiers to be used with `input()`.

You could, among other avenues, start by using `input()` with format `8.` and check that it's between, for instance, `19600101` and `20250101` (or whichever numbers are appropriate), and only then do the `input()` with `yymmdd8.`.

If you want to be more thorough, you could use `input()` with 3 substrings and check separately the year, month and day parts (using `between 1960 and 2020`, `between 1 and 12`, etc.).